# Email trigger when cell color changes in sheets

Tags: javascript

I have set up a sheet to track expiry dates of qualifications .  I have set up a formula so that once a qualification has expired the cell goes red.  Would it be possible to write a script that sends me an email every time a cell goes red.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to write a script that sends me an email...

No, but you can write a script that calls a script on your server via AJAX, that sends an e-mail.

> ...every time a cell goes red.

This is problematic.  Undoubtedly, you will change how your display works over time.  Instead, whatever code you have set up to set your cells red, have it also call your server-side script to send e-mail.